# Getting TEntity type in logging

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 in C# and have implemented my own class of `DatabaseLogFormatter` to be able to format what comes out of the log.

I would like to add some more detail to the log the TEntity object type that has executed the SQL (using thes procedure `DbSqlQuery<TEntity> SqlQuery(string sql, params object[] parameters)`). So if I had an entity named `staff` and called `staff.SqlQuery` I could in the `LogCommand()` pull out that it was `staff` that calling SQL. I could then put a line into my log `Entity "staff" executed the command...`

Answer (score 0):

Put up some code for what you have so far. It's not clear from the example procedure given it wasn't an extension method. On a guess if you want an extension method that runs against a `DbSet<TEntity>`...

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
   public static DbSqlQuery<TEntity> SqlQuery<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, string sql, params object[] parameters) where TEntity : class
   {
      // Do stuff with dbSet...
      Logger.Instance.Write(string.Replace("Entity \"{0}\" executed the command...", typeof(TEntity).Name));
   }
}
```

calling code would be something like:

```
using( var context = new myDbContext())
{
   var query = context.Orders.SqlQuery(sql);
   // ...
   var results = query.ToList();
}
```

As a static method, to access a logger you'd need to resolve it as either a static class or static Singleton. Alternatively, to just extract the name of a DbSet for use in a non-static repository method or the like:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
   public static string EntityName<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet) where TEntity : class
   {
      return typeof(TEntity).Name;
   }
}
```

Though without code it's a bit difficult to guess at how you intended that SqlQuery method to work...